# How can i use MongoDB aggregation to conditionally match fields from a search form that aren't null?

Tags: mongodb, forms, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

I have a large search form on my website with 10+ optional search parameters. I need to return all documents from MongoDB that match whichever form fields are present in each search.

One way to achieve desired results is to write if else statements for every possible combination of non empty search fields in order, but there has to be a better way.

```
    ex.
    const sQ = new TMDLs(request.body);


    }else if(sQ.Basin && sQ.Water_Body_Name && sQ.Water_Body_ID){
        searchData = await TMDLs.aggregate([
            { $match: { $text: {$search: `\"${sQ.Basin}\"`}}},
            { $match: { Water_Body_Name: sQ.Water_Body_Name}},
            { $match: { Water_Body_ID: sQ.Water_Body_ID}}

        ]);
    }else if(sQ.Basin && sQ.Water_Body_Name){
        searchData = await TMDLs.aggregate([
            { $match: { Basin: sQ.Basin }},
            { $match: {Water_Body_Name: sQ.Water_Body_Name}}
        ]);
```

The code above works but it is impractical to try every combination of non empty search parameters. I need the aggregation results to return all records that match the non empty search fields.

I've tried $ifNull, $exists, $group, $project, and many other conditional operators but I can't find anything that answers this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of structuring this problem would be to have a list of all of the searches & filter out the non-null ones:

```js
const criteria = [
            sQ.Basin != null && { $text: {$search: `\"${sQ.Basin}\"`}}},
            sQ.Water_Body_Name != null && { Water_Body_Name: sQ.Water_Body_Name}},
            sQ.Water_Body_ID != null && { $match: { Water_Body_ID: sQ.Water_Body_ID}}
            sQ.Basin != null && { Basin: sQ.Basin },
            ...
].filter(Boolean)
```

After you have those criteria, you can use `$and` to combine them into a single `$match` stage (which is equivalent to multiple serial `$match` stages).

```js
TMDLs.aggregate([
  {$match: {$and: criteria}},
  ...
])
```